# Getting error running "podman unshare chown"

Tags: containers, podman

I'm trying to run a mysql container with a persistent volume but when I run the command below I got an error guiding to use unshare with rootless:

```
$podman unshare chown 27:27 -R /home/user1/tmp
Error: please use unshare with rootless
```

Comment: What happens if you run $`chown -R xxx:xxx /home/user1/tmp` (where the xxx is the start range in /etc/subuid for your user + 26.) Will you manage to use the persistent volume within your container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved using mount option `:Z`

> $ podman run container -v /local/dir:/container/dir:Z -d image:latest